# Run Spring Integration flow concurrently for each Ftp file

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a Integration flow configured using Java DSL which pulls file from Ftp server using `Ftp.inboundChannelAdapter` then transforms it to `JobRequest`, then I have a `.handle()` method which triggers my batch job, everything is working as per required but the process in running sequentially for each file inside the FTP folder

I added `currentThreadName` in my Transformer Endpoint it was printing same thread name for each file

Here is what I have tried till now

1.task executor bean

```
 @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("Integration");

    }
```

2.Integration flow

```
  @Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) throws IOException {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(myFtpSessionFactory)
                    .remoteDirectory("/bar")
                    .localDirectory(localDir.getFile())
            ,c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).maxMessagesPerPoll(20)))
            .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest(importUserJob(step1())))
            .handle(jobLaunchingGateway)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload")
            .route(JobExecution.class,j->j.getStatus().isUnsuccessful()?"jobFailedChannel":"jobSuccessfulChannel")
            .get();
}
```

3.I also read in another SO thread that I need `ExecutorChannel` so I configured one but I don't know how to inject this channel into my `Ftp.inboundAdapter`, from logs is see that the channel is always `integrationFlow.channel#0` which I guess is a `DirectChannel`

```
 @Bean
public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
    return new ExecutorChannel(taskExecutor());
}
```

I dont know what I'm missing here, or I might have not properly understood Spring Messaging System as I'm very much new to Spring and Spring-Integration

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExecutorChannel` you can simply inject into the flow and it is going to be applied to the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` by the framework. So, having that `inputChannel` defined as a bean you just do this:

```
.channel(inputChannel())
```

before your  `.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest(importUserJob(step1())))`.
See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-channels

On the other hand to process your files in parallel according your `.taskExecutor(taskExecutor())` configuration, you just need to have a `.maxMessagesPerPoll(20)` as `1`. The logic in the `AbstractPollingEndpoint` is like this:

```
this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
```

So, we do have tasks in parallel, but only when they reach that `maxMessagesPerPoll` where it is `20` in your current case. There is also some explanation in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#endpoint-pollingconsumer

> The maxMessagesPerPoll property specifies the maximum number of messages to receive within a given poll operation. This means that the poller continues calling receive() without waiting, until either null is returned or the maximum value is reached. For example, if a poller has a ten-second interval trigger and a maxMessagesPerPoll setting of 25, and it is polling a channel that has 100 messages in its queue, all 100 messages can be retrieved within 40 seconds. It grabs 25, waits ten seconds, grabs the next 25, and so on.

Comment: So the `taskExecutor()` method in pollerspec lets poller polls message(s) and hand it off to another thread then the thread that is polling is released to poll next set of messages...is that what  is does?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are at least two threads: one for scheduling periodic task according the trigger configuration. Another one (or more) for performing the poll task. So, yes when such a poll task is performed on a different thread, the control comes back to the scheduler to start an new periodic task. Technically a downstream `ExecutorChannel` is going to give us similar side effect - as long as we shift the job to a different thread, the scheduler is good to go for the next polling cycle.

Comment: After I changed `maxMessagesPerPoll` to 1 my batch job for each file is now running on different thread even though when I dont have `ExecutorChannel` in place, So `ExecutorChannel` is helpful when poller reads two or more messages at once and hand it off to `ExecutorChannel` then the channel processes each message concurrently on different thread. `ExecutorChannel` is not required when I have `maxMessagesPerPoll` set to 1.  Correct? Just need to clarify my doubts once again I know you have explained kind of same in your answer

Comment: Your observation is correct: there is indeed no need to overhead with threads shifting if that enough for you logic.